# Displaying data from MongoDB to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was trying to display the list of the products in my database, however I'm not too sure on what to do looked up tutorials but getting different ways to do it and I wasn't able to make sense out of those tutorial.

**router**

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{
    Product.find()
        .then(results => {
            res.render('dashboard/', { Product: results }),
            res.render('dashboard/', { user: req.user })
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
});
```

**dashboard/index.ejs**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
    Product List
    <%= Product %>
</div>
```

by using **<%= Product %>** it does display the content of my database

```
{ _id: 329042tnwnh, name: 'Sample 1', price: '100', description: 'sample description', __v: 0 }
```

by using **<%= Product.name %>** it doesn't display a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use "Product.find()"   it returns an Array.

when you are passing "result" to  "<%= Product %>" you are actually passing a result Array

try

<%= Product[0].name %>     - prints first product name

<%= Product[1].name %>     - prints second product name(if you have more than one product)

<%= Product[2].name %>     - prints third product name

....
...
...

instead use loop for printing all your products name